# Is there a way to configure vim to run external commands through cpanel jailshell?

Tags: ssh, vim

I'm editing files in vim over ssh, and I'd like to save git commits and things by running external commands in vim, like `:!git add % && git commit -m "update"` but because my server (hostgator) has a limited shell, cpanel jailshell, I get the error:

```
Cannot execute shell /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell
```

Is there a way to configure the shell settings in vim so that external commands work?

Answer (score 3):

You can turn this around and use `sshfs` to mount the remote files over an `ssh` connection and use your tools that are local to your computer to interact with them (i.e. `vim` & `git`).

Take a look at this [tutorial on sshfs](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshfs).

#### Example

```
$ modprobe fuse
$ sshfs sessy@mycomputer:/home/sessy /mnt/sessy -C -p 9876
```

Now just cd into `/mnt/sessy` and use `vim` and `git` locally. When you're done unmount it.

```
$ fusermount -u /mnt/sessy
```

Comment: This is way better than editing using a remote vim. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon - If this worked would you mind accepting it so that others know your question has been resolved? Thanks.

Comment: @sim, This hack is better, but it doesn't really solve the original problem, which was that external commands weren't running in vim over ssh. Although your solution obviates the need for running stuff on my server (since I can run it locally), it'd be misleading to accept this as the answer, since others that might have the same issue won't really find the answer to this question.

Comment: @Jon - fair enough. Does your method solve the problem? It sounds like it does, if so I'd accept it instead then.

Comment: @sim, It does solve the problem. It won't let me accept it for another 17 hours for some reason.

Comment: @Jon - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting this to work by adding `set shell=/bin/bash` to my `.vimrc`.